# Android - implementing Palette class

Tags: android, palette

I am trying to implement the Palette class in my android app, however Android Studio doesn't recognize `Palette` as a class. I tried `import android.support.v7.graphics;`, but AS doesn't recognize the package either. What else do I have to do?
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Anyone looking for palette example http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/10/android-support-v7-palette-demo.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the dependency `com.android.support:palette-v7:21.0.+` to your `build.gradle` file.

See https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-palette for reference.